# Print the alphabet in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I would like help with the following algorithm in bash (or anything accessible through bash shell): I give a number to some function, and based on that number I obtain a string of alphabet letters. Example:

```
1   - A
2   - B
....
26  - Z
....
702 - ZZ
703 - AAA
```

I do not wish to occupy more memory than I need, so approaches such as `for i in {A..Z}` or `echo {A..Z}` or `echo {A..Z}{A..Z}` are not viable here. The closest I've managed to get is to find out how long is the sequence of letters for a particular number through the following expression:

```
printf %.0f\\n $(echo '(scale=20;l($number)/l(26))+0.5000000000000000001' | bc -l)
```

After that, I am stuck. A little help?

Comment: ZZ should be 702, not 676.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

alphabet=( {A..Z} )

convertToString(){
    dividend="$1"
    colName=""
    while (( dividend > 0 ))
    do
         mod=$(( (dividend-1)%26 ))
         colName="${alphabet[$mod]}$colName"
         dividend=$(( (dividend-mod)/26 ))
    done
    echo "$colName"
}

convertToString "$1"
```

Example output:

```
$ convertToString 1
A

$ convertToString 2
B

$ convertToString 27
AA

$ convertToString 702
ZZ

$ convertToString 703
AAA

$ convertToString 16384
XFD

$ convertToString 1187803
BOOBS
```

Comment: +1! But I'd change the name of `alphabets` to `letters` (or `alphabet`).

Comment: Much appreciated. Can't believe this flew right over my head.

Comment: `dividend-mod` could simply be `dividend-1` as in the previous line.

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for a quick solution to this, and came across this SO question, with no "good" answer (that is "quick"). So, here:

```
#!/bin/bash
# works up to ZZZ -- i.e., A..Z AA..ZZ AAA..ZZZ
max=$1  # e.g., max=30
echo {A..Z} $(echo {A..Z}{A..Z}) $(echo {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}) \
    | tr ' ' '\n' \
    | head -${max}
```

The comment, *"I do not wish to occupy more memory than I need, so approaches such as `echo {A..Z}{A..Z}` are not viable here"*  is nonsensical, so I post this practical solution here for posterity, those who come across this SO question in their googling.

My use-case was prefixing lines of a file with "A".."ZZ", e.g., if the script above were called `letters.sh`,

```
lines=$(wc -l my_file.txt)
paste <( cat my_file.txt )  <( letters.sh $lines )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_alpha {
    local N=$1
    __=''
    if [[ N -gt 0 ]]; then
        local CHARS=(0 {A..Z})
        while [[ N -gt 26 ]]; do
            (( M = N % 26 ))
            [[ M -eq 0 ]] && M=26
            (( N = (N - M) / 26 ))
            __=${CHARS[M]}${__}
        done
        __=${CHARS[N]}${__}
    fi
}

function print_alpha {
    get_alpha "$1"
    echo "$__"
}

print_alpha 1
print_alpha 26
print_alpha 27
print_alpha 702
print_alpha 703
```

Outputs:

```
A
Z
AA
ZZ
AAA
```

Comment: With your algorithm `print_alpha 702` yields `AA`. `print_alpha 703` yields `AAA`.

Comment: Magic global variables, boo.

Comment: @ooga The problem lies with the fact that the OP doesn't use a number/symbol equivalent to 0. I found the needed correction.

Comment: @glennjackman Way better than summoning subshells to get results e.g. `R=$(XYZ)`; or perhaps passing a custom variable name that would later be used with `eval` or similar methods to save value to. Also, it should be easy to merge both functions if wanted.

Comment: Apparently the correction wasn't needed since dogbane found a solution to the original question.

Comment: Even with `printf -v "$var" ...` you would still have to decide how you would handle invalid variable name errors and it makes things more complicated.

Comment: @ooga I'm not sure about dogbane's solution but I still need to correct mine. Besides it's an alternative in which one may find simpler or more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
received_number=$1  # Read one argument
counter=0  # Initialize counter
while [ $counter -lt $received_number ]  # while counter less or equal than received number
do  
    letter=$(($counter % 26 + 97))  # This is the integer that represents the letter
    char=$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' $letter))  # We convert the int to chr     
    n_times=$(($counter / 26))  # This is how many times we need to print it       
    final_string=""  # This is for reset the variable for each letter
    i=0
    while [ $i -le $n_times ]
    do
        final_string=$final_string$char
        i=$(( $i + 1 ))  
    done

    counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))  # Increase counter
    echo $counter " - " $final_string  
done
```

---

This script go over the number you give.

If you make `./script 10`, output is:

```
...
8  -  h
9  -  i
10  -  j
```

If you make `./script 26`, output is the full alphabet:

```
...  ...  ...
23  -  w
24  -  x
25  -  y
26  -  z
```

If you make `./script 52`:

```
...  ...  ...
48  -  vv
49  -  ww
50  -  xx
51  -  yy
52  -  zz
```

If you make `./script 78`:

```
...  ...  ...
74  -  vvv
75  -  www
76  -  xxx
77  -  yyy
78  -  zzz
```

and so on...